# Couldnt open 7z file with random password generated by powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Below script able to generate 7z file and encrypted with password. However, I couldn't open the file with password. What happened to my script?

Tools

1. Powershell v2
2. .NET 4
3. Window Server 2008

Below script unable open the 7z file with password.

(Error I got >> .\staff_2019-11-02.7z: Checksum error in the encrypted file .\staff_2019-11-02.7z. Corrupt file or wrong password.)

Password generated by powershell = e+p@Bcr2 (eg of password)

> ```
> [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web")
> $randomPassword = [System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(8,2)
>
> if (-not (test-path "C:\7-Zip\7z.exe")) {throw "C:\7-Zip\7z.exe needed"}
> set-alias sz "C:\7-Zip\7z.exe"
>
> $timestamp = Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd
> $Source = ".\staff.txt"
> $Target = ".\staff_$timestamp.7z"
> $outputPassword = ".\staff_Password.txt"
>
> sz a -mx=0 -p$randomPassword -mhe=on -m0=lzma2 $Target $Source | Out-Null
>
> Write-Output "staff_$timestamp.7z password is $randomPassword" | Out-file $outputPassword  -Append
> ```

Able to open 7z file with password **Abc123**

```
if (-not (test-path "C:\7-Zip\7z.exe")) {throw "C:\7-Zip\7z.exe needed"}
set-alias sz "C:\7-Zip\7z.exe"

$timestamp = Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd
$Source = ".\staff.txt"
$Target = ".\staff_$timestamp.7z"
$outputPassword = ".\staff_Password.txt"

sz a -mx=0 -pAbc123-mhe=on -m0=lzma2 $Target $Source | Out-Null
```

Comment: Ok, but how does the last statement look like when you are using the password from the file?

Comment: As far as I see, you are generating a new password each time but you are storing it in the same file, by appending a sentence to its end. In that case, you will need to retrieve the last "word" of that row of the password file where the date corresponds to the archive date you want to open. But if you take the whole file content or a row from the file you will not use the actual password. But this is just a guess as you have not shared that statement.

Comment: @zorgoz what u mean by last statement? The purpose of storing the password in a text file because i need to test i really can open the 7z with the password generated by powershell. However, each time i hit the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect its the PowerShell parser, try this

```
sz a -mx=0 $('-p' + $randomPassword) -mhe=on -m0=lzma2 $Target $Source
```